# How can I solve FAILURE: Execution failed for task ':rive_common:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, rive

I got this error while trying to build my flutter application

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':rive_common:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: ninja: Entering directory `/home/mcrops/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/rive_common-0.2.7/android/.cxx/Debug/13194d4d/arm64-v8a'
  [1/64] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rive_text.dir/home/mcrops/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/rive_common-0.2.7/ios/rive-cpp/src/rive_counter.cpp.o
  FAILED: CMakeFiles/rive_text.dir/home/mcrops/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/rive_common-0.2.7/ios/rive-cpp/src/rive_counter.cpp.o 
  /home/mcrops/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --sysroot=/home/mcrops/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot -Drive_text_EXPORTS -I../../../../../ios/harfbuzz/src -I../../../../../ios/rive-cpp/skia/renderer/include -I../../../../../ios/rive-cpp/include -I../../../../../ios/SheenBidi/Headers -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -DWITH_RIVE_TEXT -DHAVE_OT -DHB_NO_FALLBACK_SHAPE -DHB_NO_WIN1256 -std=c++11 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/rive_text.dir/home/mcrops/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/rive_common-0.2.7/ios/rive-cpp/src/rive_counter.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/rive_text.dir/home/mcrops/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/rive_common-0.2.7/ios/rive-cpp/src/rive_counter.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/rive_text.dir/home/mcrops/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/rive_common-0.2.7/ios/rive-cpp/src/rive_counter.cpp.o -c /home/mcrops/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/rive_common-0.2.7/ios/rive-cpp/src/rive_counter.cpp
  In file included from /home/mcrops/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/rive_common-0.2.7/ios/rive-cpp/src/rive_counter.cpp:5:
  In file included from ../../../../../ios/rive-cpp/include/rive/rive_counter.hpp:8:
  In file included from ../../../../../ios/rive-cpp/include/rive/rive_types.hpp:12:
  /snap/flutter/current/usr/include/c++/9/memory:121:25: error: cast from pointer to smaller type 'uintptr_t' (aka 'unsigned int') loses information
    const auto __intptr = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(__ptr);
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  [2/64] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rive_text.dir/home/mcrops/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/rive_common-0.2.7/ios/rive-cpp/src/text/line_breaker.cpp.o
  FAILED: CMakeFiles/rive_text.dir/home/mcrops/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/rive_common-0.2.7/ios/rive-cpp/src/text/line_breaker.cpp.o 


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be because of the conflict in the cache,
Trying doing this things,this will definitely resolve the problems:

1. "flutter clean" and then again install the apps.
2. if above didnot work, try deleting the pod file located in ios folder and try to install app again.
3. Make sure your dart version is compatible with the rive that you are using.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work

Comment: in 3 point, I already mentioned the compatibility of your rive package with dart SDK.

Answer (score 0):

After long hours of debuging, I was able to solve the error by removing this package `awesome_dialog:` from my pubspec.yaml file. Am still not sure why it was causing the issue